# I want call unix command in cocoa application,but it doesn't work,

Tags: cocoa, unix, command

I want call unix command in cocoa application,but it doesn't work,

the command:"lua -v"

cocoa code:

```
NSArray *cmdArray = [cmd componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
task.launchPath = cmdArray[0];
if(cmdArray.count > 1)
{
    task.arguments = [cmdArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, cmdArray.count - 1)];
}
[task launch] ;
NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
[file closeFile] ;

NSString *grepOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return grepOutput;
```

the data always is 0 byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTask` does not run a Unix "command", rather it runs a Unix "process", and the difference is crucial.

When your code is run in Xcode you should see "launch path not accessible" in the console window, this is your clue as to the problem. The documentation for `launch` tells you that an exception is thrown if the launch path is invalid.

When you type, say, "echo Hello" at the Unix command prompt you are entering data into a command interpreter, the "shell". The shell has to locate the application "echo" in order to start a process running it. The shell does this by searching through a set of directories specified by the `PATH` environment variable, in the case of "echo" it finds "/bin/echo". It is this path you must set the `launchPath` property to.

If you wish to use `NSTask` for this purpose you have two basic choices (a) have your code locate the "lua" binary itself or (b) use `NSTask` to run a shell and have that shell do its normal processing for you.

The standard "sh" shell is located at "/bin/sh". If you read it's manual page you will see it takes an option "-c *string*" which instructs it to treat *string* as command input. E.g consider the following Terminal transcript:

```
crd$ echo Hello
Hello
crd$ sh -c "echo Hello"
Hello
crd$
```

In the first case the shell found the binary for "echo" and executed that passing it "Hello". In the second it found the binary for "sh" and executed that passing it "-c" and "echo Hello", that process in turn found the binary for "echo".

So using `NSTask` you can invoke "/bin/sh" and pass it as arguments "-c" and your command line, the shell will then parse your command line just like in the Terminal and invoke your command, something along the lines of:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.standardOutput = pipe;
task.standardError =pipe;  // capture any error messages the sh writes, could send to another pipe
task.launchPath = @"/bin/sh";
task.arguments = @[@"-c", cmd];

[task launch];
NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
[file closeFile];
```

HTH